# iPad Pro Stage Manager and Vuforia/Unity lost tracking when placed in background

Tags: unity-game-engine, ipad, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have created a Unity/Vuforia area target application. The user is able to move around our facility and view AR objects and trainings on the latest Ipad pro. When a user either accidentally hits the power button, or slides up on the device, it sends the app into a paused state. upon return the tracking is having issues resetting.

I have the tracking disabled temporarily until the pause is over, however upon returning, the tracking is incorrect.

How can I correctly pause and resume tracking in the correct location?

Comment: please read [tour] and [ask]